# Cohomology of blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, blowup

I read from somewhere the following proposition (maybe more condition needed):

> Let $X$ be a $\mathbb C$-scheme, $Z$ its closed subscheme. Let $B=Bl_Z X$ be the blow-up along $Z$ and $E$ be the exceptional divisor. Then we have $$H^*(B)\oplus H^*(Z)=H^*(X)\oplus H^*(E)$$ where $H^*$ is the cohomology ring.

I want to know its proof.

**My Attampt:**  Since we have $B\backslash E \cong X\backslash Z$, so it should be natural to have $$H^*(B)\ominus H^*(E)=H^*(X)\ominus H^*(Z)$$ and then follows the result. However, I don't know how to formulate the "$\ominus$" in a good way. But I believe this should make sense.

Comment: What kind of cohomology are you talking about?

Comment: @EricWofsey In fact I am not very sure... I suppose it is singular cohomology.

Comment: If things are smooth, use Mayer Vietoris.

Comment: It is almost certainly not supposed to be singular cohomology, at least as stated--singular cohomology is not natural at all for schemes.  Maybe instead of schemes they are supposed to be complex analytic spaces.

Comment: You said you read this from somewhere. Can you state the reference?

Comment: @EricWofsey  Yeah, it should be $\mathbb C$-scheme then it makes sense. I edited it.

Comment: @JohnMa It's from my lecture notes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Could you say a little more about how to use MV sequence?

Comment: Suppose first that Z is a point. Pick a small open ball U round it in X and the complement of a small closed disc V centered at Z and contained in B. In the blowup, the preimages are an open $\tilde U$, which is just $U$, and a $\tilde V$ which you can easily see to deformation retract onto the $P^n$ which is the fiber over $Z$. The intersection is just a sphere.

Comment: For general smooth Z, things work in the same way. Pick a tubular neighborhood of Z and a complement of a smaller tubular neighborhood. One of them does not change in the blowup and the other deformation retracts onto something which is the projectivization of the normal bundle of  Z in X.

Comment: This is done in detail in the book by Griffith and Harris, iirc.